some items are missing in the root control group in cgroups v2
I'm using cgroups v2 in my ubuntu24.04, and I'm confused about the root control group because some items are missing compared to the non-root control group, taking cpu controller for example:
$ ll /sys/fs/cgroup/
...
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Nov 27 16:46 cpu.pressure
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Nov 27 16:46 cpu.stat
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Nov 27 16:46 cpu.stat.local
...

there are only three items for the cpu contoller but ten:
$ ll /sys/fs/cgroup/test/
...
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.idle
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.max
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.max.burst
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.pressure
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.stat
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.stat.local
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.uclamp.max
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.uclamp.min
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.weight
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 0 Dec  2 20:41 cpu.weight.nice
...

all controllers all enabled in the root control group:
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers 
cpuset cpu io memory hugetlb pids rdma misc

why are there only three items in the root control group for cpu controller? what makes the root control group so special?

One explanation might be that those three items are common to all cpu controllers.

The root cgroup acts as the parent of all other cgroups and is an administrative entry point. It focuses on enabling a hierarchical structure for the resource control in child cgroups.
And it does not manage tasks like the childs where ressource limits etc are applied; instead, it aggregates data and controls for all child cgroups like I already mentioned.
Edit:
Root cgroup doesn't apply resource constraints like CPU limits or memory limits directly to the child tasks

no I don't think so, /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs will show you the tasks that the root cgroup manage.

I should be more precise sorry for that. it doesn't apply resource constraints like CPU limits or memory limits directly to these tasks

It's hard to understand why it is so. If I were the maintainer of cgroups, since the root cgroup already exists and there are so many processes belonging to the root cgroup, why not enable the root cgroup to have the function of limiting process resources?

By delegating resource management to child cgroups, the system remains flexible and less prone to errors or misconfigurations that could arise if the root cgroup also enforced resource limits. While it seems logical to use the root cgroup for resource limits given its scope, doing so could introduce complications:
It risks creating conflicts between system-wide constraints and hierarchical control +
many system processes are not meant to be constrained and rely on unrestricted access to resources

If you want to enforce resource limits globally, you can create a child cgroup (e.g., /sys/fs/cgroup/global-limits/) and assign all non-critical processes to it. This approach maintains the integrity of the root cgroup while still achieving your goal.

many system processes are not meant to be constrained and rely on unrestricted access to resources  seems a valid reason for why root cgroup might not support resource limitations.
